# Displaying pop ups for overlapping polygons in the same layer in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, popup

I am working on a leaflet map that shows property ownership over time with polygons and a time slider (https://github.com/jeffjb4488/GeoJASON_test). However, some of my polygons overlap and only the popup for the topmost layer appears.

I came across a solution for a popup that shows tabs for multiple geojson layers (http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/pointsinpoly/indextab.html).

I am wondering if there was a way to make this work to display tabs for multiple polygons in the same geojson layer?

Code snippet:

```
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script id="rendered-js" >
    var basemap_color = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var basemap_satellite = 'https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/satellite-v2/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg?key=kUPH9bhggOn8sGeOtVCW';
    var overlay_1890 = 'https://map-tile.server.burne138.msu.domains/Plan_Map_of_the_Highlands_1890_best_imagery_4326_largest/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    
    
    var map = L.map('map', {
        editable: true,
        minZoom: 13,
        maxZoom: 20,
        zoomControl: false}).setView([41.461070584121636, -70.56516015402862], 16);
    
    var basemapLayerColor = L.tileLayer(basemap_color, {
      noWrap: true,
      minZoom: 13,
      maxZoom: 20,
      attribution: '<div id="content-attribution">&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> </div>'
    }).addTo(map);
    
    var basemapLayerSatellite = L.tileLayer(basemap_satellite,{
            noWrap: true,
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            maxZoom: 20,
            minZoom: 13,
            attribution: '<div id="content-attribution">&copy; <a href="https://www.maptiler.com/" target="_blank">MapTiler</a> contributors JJB |</div>',
            crossOrigin: true
          }).addTo(map);
    
    var overlayLayer1890 = L.tileLayer(overlay_1890, {
      noWrap: true,
      maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom: 13,
      opacity: 0.6,
      attribution: '<div id="content-attribution">Historic Map, <a href="https://collections.leventhalmap.org/search/commonwealth:x059cd109" target="_blank">Boston Public Library Norman B. Leventhal Map Center</div>',
    }).addTo(map);
    
    var baseMaps = {
        "Satellite": basemapLayerSatellite,
        "Standard": basemapLayerColor
       };
    
    var overlayMaps = {
        "Historic Map": overlayLayer1890
    };
    
    var mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width:991px)');
    
    let mobileView = mql.matches;    
    
    var mobileZoomBox =  L.Control.extend({
    
    options: {
      position: 'topright'
    },
     
    onAdd: function (map) {
      var container = L.DomUtil.create('div');
      container.type="div";
      container.title="Mobile Zoom Box";
      container.textContent = 'Pinch To Zoom';
      
      container.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      container.style.fontSize = "22px";
      container.style.fontWeight = "700";
      container.style.textAlign = "center";
      container.style.backgroundSize = "100px 65px";
      container.style.width = '100px';
      container.style.height = '65px';
      
    
      return container;
    }
    });
    
    if (mobileView) {
        map.addControl(new mobileZoomBox());;
    } else {
        var zoom_bar = new L.Control.ZoomBar({position: 'topright'}).addTo(map);
    }
    
    
    L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
    
    var infoDesktop = L.control();
    var infoMobile = L.control();
    
    infoDesktop.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };
    
    infoMobile.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };
    
    // method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
    infoDesktop.update = function (props) {
            this._div.innerHTML = '<div id="content-desktop"><h3>Lot Information</h3>' +  (props ?
            '<b>' + 'Lot #' + props.lot_number + ' owned by ' + props.grantee + ' starting on ' + props.time
            : 'Hover over a lot</div>');
        };
        
    infoMobile.update = function (props) {
            this._div.innerHTML = '<div id="content-mobile"><h2>Lot Information</h2>' +  (props ?
            '<b>' : '<h3>Click on a lot</h3></div>');
            };
    
    if (mobileView) {
        infoMobile.addTo(map);
    } else {
        infoDesktop.addTo(map);
    }
    
    
    function style(feature) {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'black',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                fillColor: 'green',
            };
        }
    
    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;
    
        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });
    
        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        };
    
        infoDesktop.update(layer.feature.properties);
        infoMobile.update(layer.feature.properties);
    }
    
    var polygons
    
    
    
        function resetHighlight(e) {
            polygons.resetStyle(e.target);
            infoDesktop.update();
            infoMobile.update();
        }
    
        function zoomToFeature(e) {
            map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
        }
        
      function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            dblclick: zoomToFeature,
        });
    
      
    
        
        var content = "<div style='clear: both'></div><div><center><img src='images/" + feature.properties.picture + "' style='width:200px;height:300x;'></center> <br><h4>" + 'Lot number ' + feature.properties.lot_number + "</h4><p>" + feature.properties.time + "</p><p>" + feature.properties.grantee + "</p><a href='" + feature.properties.link + "' target='_blank'>" + "Click here for more info" + "</a>" + "</p></div>";
        layer.bindPopup(content, {closeButton: true});
        var p = layer.feature.properties;
        p.index = "Lot " + p.lot_number + " | " + p.grantee + " | " + p.time;
        };
    
    
        $.getJSON("data/test_polygon_wgs84_5.geojson", function (json){
    // add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
       polygons = L.geoJson(json ,{
            style: style,
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
            });map.fitBounds(polygons.getBounds());
    
    // Set the sliderControl options
        var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
            layer: polygons, //REQUIRED
            alwaysShowDate: true,
            range: true,
            sameDate: true,
            showAllPopups: false, // to show all popups, instead of one, same as popup option "autoClose: false"
            showPopups: false, // to set it so, when a marker is generated by the slider, its popup doesn't automatically display
            showAllOnStart: true        
        });
    
    
    
        var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
            layer: polygons,
            propertyName: 'index',
            marker: false,
            moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
                //map.fitBounds( latlng.layer.getBounds() );
                var zoom = map.getBoundsZoom(latlng.layer.getBounds());
                map.setView(latlng, zoom); // access the zoom
            }
    });        
    
    searchControl.on('search:locationfound', function(e) {
            
            //console.log('search:locationfound', );
    
            //map.removeLayer(this._markerSearch)
    
            e.layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#3f0', color: '#0f0'});
            if(e.layer._popup)
                e.layer.openPopup();
    
        }).on('search:collapsed', function(e) {
    
            polygons.eachLayer(function(layer) {    //restore feature color
                polygons.resetStyle(layer);
            }); 
    });
        
    map.addControl( searchControl );  //inizialize search control
        
    // Add the slider to the map
    map.addControl(sliderControl);
    
    // Initialize the slider
    sliderControl.startSlider();
    
    });
    
    var sidebar = L.control.sidebar({ container: 'sidebar' })
                .addTo(map)
                .open('home');
    
    
    
    
    </script>
    
      
    
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On way to do it is to use your click processing function `zoomToFeature` and there with the help of [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library function `turf.booleanPointInPolygon` check which features contain clicked point coordinate and then build and open your popup there, instead of defining popup in `onEachFeature` function.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
function zoomToFeature(e) {
  map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
  var point = turf.point([e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat]);
  var content = '';
  polygons.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    var feature = layer.feature;
    if (turf.booleanPointInPolygon(point, feature)) {
      content += "<div style='clear: both'></div><div><center><img src='images/" + feature.properties.picture + "' style='width:200px;height:300x;'></center> <br><h4>" + 'Lot number ' + feature.properties.lot_number + "</h4><p>" + feature.properties.time + "</p><p>" + feature.properties.grantee + "</p><a href='" + feature.properties.link + "' target='_blank'>" + "Click here for more info" + "</a>" + "</p></div>";
    }
  });
  L.popup()
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent(content)
    .openOn(map);
}

function onEachFeature (feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
    mouseover: highlightFeature,
    mouseout: resetHighlight,
    click: zoomToFeature
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I have successfully added the Turf code and its seems to be calling the popup through there, but only one appears still. Should i be moving my original content variable to where yours just has the double quotes?

Comment: Thank you - this now works full - I simply had to remove the my old bindpopup line. Thank you very much. This worked perfectly.